# Is a Polish PhD degree in engineering equally respected in North America?

Tags: phd, europe, poland

Is a Polish PhD degree in engineering equally revered as a North American degree (i.e., from Canada or USA) in the area of academia and job-market?

Comment: In the job market, depending on the engineering specialty, you may have difficulty getting a license to practice, for instance, as a civil engineer. Each state will have different licensing requirements.

Comment: In academia, in addition to the degree they will consider your thesis (and other publications) and your recommendations.  They will not care where your PhD was obtained.

Answer (score 2):

No, it generally wouldn't be as revered. If you look at the university ranking systems, Polish institutions are generally not as  well ranked, or regarded as North American institutions. This is also true if you look at the specific rating given for the quality of engineering education within these universities. For example, see:

http://www.topuniversities.com/qs-world-university-rankings
https://www.timeshighereducation.com/world-university-rankings

Comment: But would it be as well regarded as an equivalently ranked North American institution?

Comment: Yes probably - if the person in question already knows the ranking of both the Polish institution and North American Institution. However, outside of Poland and eastern Europe people will generally be more familiar with North American institutions than Polish institutions. If I get a degree in Yale then I can probably get by with that degree anywhere in the world as the reputation is global. On the other-hand, if I have the same degree from Poland university (which is actually equally well ranked but no-one knows) it will be quite a lot hard for me to get the same benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

It is equivalent, in the sense that a PhD from Yale and MIT are "equivalent" (but, depending on department, not equivalently revered).